# Extracting datetime to year but results in float

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My datetime has a format 2009-01-23. When I try to just extract the year in a new column I get a `float`.

```
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
```

I get the result as 2009.0 and the `dtype` is `float`.

How do I get just 2009?

Comment: Hi, Please add your code in a code block. try this: `df['year'] = int(df['Date'].dt.year)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I tried it. But I get this error - TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an integer, like so:

```
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(numpy.int64)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I tried it. But I get this error - TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: @user2830993 that's weird... are you sure that `df['year']` is type `float`?

Comment: @user2830993 aha! type `float` is not the same as type `float64`. `float64` is a `numpy` type. Use `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(numpy.int64)` instead.

Comment: Got it! I tried it. I have some Null values in the column and I get this error.               ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df['year'] = int(df['Date'].dt.year)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I tried it. But I get this error - TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>